# Php and strings inside code

Tags: php, string

I have one code , when execute this code i let do other thing , for example :

```
<?php

if ($ending=="ok")
{
    $insert_end="ok";
}  

if ($insert_end=="ok")
{
    print "ok";
}

?>
```

**But if i go the url and put for example :**

http://www.domain.com/index.php?insert_end=ok

Execute the code and i don´t want this be possible because if some people know this can execute the code , it´s possible no let execute the code when put in url

Thank´s Regards

Comment: Also where is this? Your view, your controller?

Comment: Yes the controller if all ok put $insert_end="ok"; but if i put the same in the url execute all , also , by this my question if it´s possible no let this inside url , thank´s

Comment: Don't do `$insert_end = $_GET['insert_end']` if you don't want the user to be able to set it.

Comment: I never use GET , you can see in the example

Answer (score 2):

Disable `register_globals` in your `php.ini` file. It should not be used for exactly this reason.

Comment: It's also worth noting that an upgrade is advisable, register_globals was removed in 5.4.

Comment: I have disable register globals and when y send by url this , always execute in the internal code

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand, try this:

```
if ($insert_end=="ok" && !array_key_exists('insert_end', $_GET))
{
    print "ok";
}
```